# MariaDB Maxscale returns the result of a different query

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, galera, maxscale

I currently work on a Java batch application which writes and reads data to a MariaDB Maxscale Galera Cluster with a connection pool. This involves 50-100 read/write operations every second.
An issue that we face frequently is that the results of queries are interchanges.
For e.g. If three queries A, B, and C are executed, the result of A is received for B, etc.
Could this be fixed by changes in JDBC or Maxscale?

Comment: Can you add which version of MaxScale you're using? You should also see if the result for A is an error that MaxScale somehow ends up generating. This does sound like it could be a bug in MaxScale.

Comment: We use Maxscale 2.3.17

Comment: You could try to use a newer version of MaxScale (e.g. MaxScale 2.5.18) to see if this is an old problem that was fixed in a newer release. I'd at least recommend upgrading to the latest 2.3 release which is 2.3.20.